# Office 2007 removal will the email data be saved or disacarded

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have office 2007 installed. If I remove 2007 and than install office 2013 than will my whole outlook current email data with the pst file be transferred to outlook 2013.

If I remove outlook 2007 than will my emails and its data remain intact. they wont be removed with the office 2007?

Answer (score 0):

When you do an uninstall, there is normally an option to 'Remove personal data' (or something similarly worded. Dont check this, and im sure 2013 will be smart enough to search existing directories, assuming you did a standard install.

As a side note, I would strongly encourage manually keeping a backup of the PST file.
Firstly, its just good practice to regularly backup your data
Also, do the math, how long will it take to manually copy the pst file, vs trying to restore all that old data if something goes wrong. From my perspective, those few seconds now could save ours of pain. That way you can always manually restore the PST file into outlook if it all goes pear shaped.